# Making a FTP connection in Android

Tags: java, android, networking, android-source

i am working to make a Android application that can upload and download data from android phone to server using this [link](http://www.lysesoft.com/products/andftp/intent.html#download).

As i am new to connection Android with server.
is my local host works as a server to download and upload.
i am using

```
          Uri ftpUri = Uri.parse("ftp://10.0.2.2");
```

But its not working help me to get out of this problem.

I need your help just to sucessfullt connect to server, As i already said i aam new to connect Android Application to server. 
I am learning Programing myself and Internet is my teacher.

Thank You Very Much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to download the apache net library :
http://commons.apache.org/net/download_net.cgi

and to include it in your "libs" directory to make it available at build/run time in your android project.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the basic JAVA utilities for this with the Apache commons ftp package. This isn't specific to Android.

5 minutes on google, or 10 using your JAVA reference book will tell you how to do it. Here is the documentation:

http://commons.apache.org/net/